# Angular ui bootstrap popover trigger not work in newest versions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Using Angular-ui-bootstrap popover, in new versions stopped working triggers.

In this example everything works:

[WORKING](http://plnkr.co/edit/SBX3GPUFLYaKnjATbFtQ?p=preview)

I made same example with new versions and now it doesn't work:

```
$element.triggerHandler(POPOVER_SHOW);
```

This line not opens popover despite registered trigger.

[NOT WORKING](http://plnkr.co/edit/SDIkqfIdJxNm7cvb1sBP?p=preview)

maybe someone knows why? What have changed?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<script src="https://rawgit.com/Elijen/angular-popover-toggle/v0.0.10/popover-toggle.js"></script>` include in your view.

Your console is throwing an `failed to instantiate popover-toggle` error.

Comment: there is `tool.js` file updated `popover-toggle.js` to work with new version.